# How to send http request to Stripe instead of curl request?

Tags: elixir, httpoison

I can send curl request to Stripe API successfully, just like this:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers?limit=3 \
  -u sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: \
  -G
```

How can I do with Elixir dependency: HTTPoison, to send an HTTP request?

Comment: Paste that command into https://curlconverter.com/elixir/

Answer (score 2):

`HTTPoison` module has a `get` function to make `HTTP GET` requests.

You can run `h HTTPoison.get` in your `iex` to get a useful help message.

Its a good practice to start up `iex` with your libraries loaded and explore the functions you need with various values and inspect the data that is returned or generated.

In this case, something like this should get you started:

```
url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers?limit=3"
headers = [ {"Authorization", "Bearer " <> "sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"} ]

case HTTPoison.get(url, headers, []) do
  {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{body: body, status_code: 200}} -> 
      # some data is returned
      "success body = " <> Poison.decode!(body)
  {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: other_status_code}} -> 
      # api was not able to process our request, check body for details
      "some error returned from endpoint"
  {:error, reason} -> 
      "problem with network or reaching/getting endpoint"
end
```

.

The `Poison.decode!(body)` part will be somthing like this

```
%{
  "data" => [
    %{
      "account_balance" => 0,
      "address" => nil,
      "created" => 1555667607,
      "currency" => nil,
      "default_source" => "card_xxxxxxxxxx",
      "delinquent" => false,
      "description" => nil,
      "discount" => nil,
      "email" => "xxx@exemple.com",
      "id" => "cus_xxxxxxxxx",
      "invoice_prefix" => "ASDSADASD",
      "invoice_settings" => %{
        "custom_fields" => nil,
        "default_payment_method" => nil,
        "footer" => nil
      },
      "livemode" => false,
      "metadata" => %{},
      "name" => nil,
      "object" => "customer",
      "phone" => nil,
      "preferred_locales" => [],
      "shipping" => nil,
      "sources" => %{
        "data" => [
          %{
            "address_city" => nil,
            "address_country" => nil,
            "address_line1" => nil,
            "address_line1_check" => nil,
            "address_line2" => nil,
            "address_state" => nil,
            "address_zip" => nil,
            "address_zip_check" => nil,
            "brand" => "Visa",
            "country" => "US",
            "customer" => "cus_EuirEmfjcPKg4Q",
            "cvc_check" => nil,
            "dynamic_last4" => nil,
            "exp_month" => 4,
            "exp_year" => 2020,
            "fingerprint" => "XXXXXXc",
            "funding" => "credit",
            "id" => "card_123123XXX",
            "last4" => "4242",
            "metadata" => %{},
            "name" => nil,
            "object" => "card",
            "tokenization_method" => nil
          }
        ],
        "has_more" => false,
        "object" => "list",
        "total_count" => 1,
        "url" => "/v1/customers/cus_EEEEASDSADAS/sources"
      },
      "subscriptions" => %{
        "data" => [],
        "has_more" => false,
        "object" => "list",
        "total_count" => 0,
        "url" => "/v1/customers/cus_EERASDASD/subscriptions"
      },
      "tax_info" => nil,
      "tax_info_verification" => nil
    },

    ------ more objects in array here, removed for brewity -------

  ],
  "has_more" => true,
  "object" => "list",
  "url" => "/v1/customers"
}
```

Comment: thanks, i run `mix deps.get`, but a get information blow: HTTPoison.start/0 is undefined(module HTTPoison is not available)

Comment: Try running `Application.ensure_all_started(:httpoison)` in your iex. This checks if the application is loaded and started. You can see list of started applications using `Application.started_applications`.

Comment: thanks anyway, i give up testing in iex,because i can run it in my application....

Comment: Did you run iex with `iex -S mix` in the directory where your mix.exs is present? Programming interactively with iex is one of the highlights of languages like elixir :))

Comment: Jesus, that's it, u helped me a lot dude,since learning Elixir , i always using `iex` instead of using `iex -S mix`, what a bad luck...